# Are there single words for being within two bounds exclusive and non-exclusive?

Tags: terminology, upper-lower-bounds

When $a <= b <= c$ is there a single word that describes $b$ being between $a$ and $c$ (inclusive)? Is $b$ *within* $a$ and $c$?

Similarly, when $a < b < c$ is there a single word that describes $b$ being between the bounds $a$ and $c$a (exclusive)? Is $b$ *between* $a$ and $c$?

---

It seems like we can say $a$ *to* $c$ to mean $[a, c]$ and $a$ *until* $c$ to mean $[a, c)$ so I am curious if there are succinct ways of describing a value within open and closed intervals (*until* in this example is half-open so is not exactly the same).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why not just say $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: *between* and *strictly between*, respectively

Comment: Both suggestions are great. Thanks. I have clarified the question to ask specifically if there is a single word for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might say that b is bounded by a and c.

Extending this a little, and possibly creating some terminology, you might say the bound is inclusive if equality is possible and exclusive if equality is not.

So you might say that b is exclusively lower bounded by a and inclusively upper bounded by c.

Or, to be traditional, a less than b less than or equal to c.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apologies, I have clarified the question to specifically ask if there is a single word for it.